# Issue trying to take data that is being loaded and displaying it to the appropriate textfields

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, playframework, store

I am trying to get information that is being loaded in an object and display that data onto my web page. Right now, I have a .html file which contains this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var res = {"address":"","city":"","state":"","zip":""};
</script>
```

Then, I have a .js file which conists of my layout and design. and my entire store. This is the code that I created have so far, but I am not sure what the correct method is to try and get the data from the html file and display it on my js file.

```
var newStore= new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: ['address', 'city', 'state', 'zip'],
    loadData: (res),
    idIndex: 0 
});
```

Could someone please help me as I am a bit lost on what to do?

Answer (score 1):

`loadData` is a method, not a config param.  Use `data` instead, and give it an array:

```
var newStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: ['address', 'city', 'state', 'zip'],
    data: [res]
});
```

Comment: You currently have `res` defined as a global variable, so you could technically leave it wherever you want (though you should avoid using globals as much as possible).  As for your other question, you should probably take a look at the docs for `TextField`.  The `value` config will set the initial value there.

Comment: I mean no disrespect, but I think you might be best served reading up a bit on the basics of JavaScript before you go too much further.  The line `value: get('city')` is clearly going to fail because you are just randomly attempting to call a global function called `get()`.  If your model is definitely populated correctly, you can access the `city` field using `model.get('city')`.